Linkedin does not recognize my site's Wordpress URL in the "Featured" section
So I am trying to unsuccessfully add a link to my WP site within linkedin's "featured" section. I get the following error after pasting my URL:
enter image description here
In order to verify, I tried adding other random WP urls to the same section and they work just fine.
enter image description here
I checked my URL on the Linkedin Post Inspector and it is OK (OG tags as well). Here:
enter image description here
I checked the OG tags, cleared cache, talked to the developer that created the site and still cannot find a solution
